# In GitHub enterprise, how can I trigger workflow on any commit done on any branch

Tags: github, github-actions

I want to trigger a workflow whenever a commit is done on any branch in Repo, what event shall I use?

Answer (score 1):

Independently from being a Personal or an Enterprise account, it can be achieved by using the [push event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#push):

> Runs your workflow when you push a commit or tag.

Example:

```
on:
  push
```

*Observation: To trigger every single time a push is made, be sure to configure the push event **without** informing any subtype ([paths](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-affects-specific-files), [branches](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-to-specific-branches-occurs), [tags](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-workflow-only-when-a-push-of-specific-tags-occurs),  ...)*

Comment: Thanks GuiFalourd,  With "on PUSH" event, it also gets triggered when a new branch is created, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think you can achieve this with the `on` trigger alone, because if you add a [**ignore** subtype](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushbranchestagsbranches-ignoretags-ignore) this will also apply to commits. A workaround could be to use an expression for the job to run or not, but the workflow will trigger every time anyway, it just would execute the job inside it if the condition inside the expression is met (here, if it's not a branch creation).